# WinForm: Javascript error communicating with WinForm

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms

I am working on an application to implement two-way communication between a website and a C# WebForm. The WebForm is able to communicate to the webpage's script via a button, but the script cannot communicate with the webform. When clicked, the button gives the error:

`'window.external' is null or not an object.`

C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FirstCSharpApp
{
    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WebBrowser.AllowWebBrowserDrop = false;
            WebBrowser.IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = false;
            WebBrowser.WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled = false;
            WebBrowser.ObjectForScripting = this;

            string curDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            WebBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(String.Format("file:///{0}/Timeline.html", curDir)));
        }

        private void GoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Works!
            WebBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("test",
                new String[] { "called from client code" });
        }

        private void homeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WebBrowser.GoHome();
        }

        private void goBackToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WebBrowser.GoBack();
        }

        private void goForwardToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WebBrowser.GoForward();
        }

        public void Test(String message)
        {
            // Does not work, or apparently even exist
            MessageBox.Show(message, "client code");
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function test(message) {
            alert(message);
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <button onclick ="window.external.Test('called from script')">
        Call client code.
    </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @MatthewMartin Well Microsoft better educate themselves then, this is copied from their tutorial. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0746166.aspx

Comment: @MatthewMartin This is an html page in an embedded WebBrowser control.  `window.external` is coupled to `WebBrowser.ObjectForScripting`  - ie this should be fine

Comment: @JamesThorpe keyword: should. Any more wisdom? I've gotten nowhere with this in 3 days.

Answer (score 0):

The following two lines solved my issue. There was no accompanying or relevant error, it was by random luck that I saw the dependency was not declared.

```
// new
using System.Security;
...
// already in code
[PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
```